# Bash Script to Deploy

Tags: bash, deployment, while-loop, case-statement

I have a script that deploys to either firebase or heroku. At the end of the script, if I fat finger an extra key or misspell heroku or firebase, I want the script to prompt me to input the desired host and run the script again from the top with my desired input. I tried putting a while loop outside a case statement. My hope was that when the script reaches the final `*)` it will prompt me to input the desired host, start the script from the top and deploy to the desired host.

Being fairly new to scripting, I'm not 100% sure this is how/the best way to write it, but when I run the script as `deploy heroku` or `deploy firebase` with the below code, literally, nothing happens on the terminal. I've tried quotes around `"$?"` and moved the `exit 1` around, but still nothing. Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Also, I run this script in terminal by calling

`deploy <placetodeploy>`

```
#!/bin/bash

 HOST=$1

 while [ $? -gt 0 ]; do
   case "$HOST" in
     heroku)
      git push heroku master
      ;;
    firebase)
      firebase deploy
      ;;
    *)
      read -p "You can only choose between Heroku and Firebase. " HOST; exit 1                                                           
      ;;
   esac
 done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

 HOST=$1
 while true; do
   case "$HOST" in
     heroku)
      git push heroku master
      break
      ;;
    firebase)
      firebase deploy
      break
      ;;
    *)
      read -p "You can only choose between Heroku and Firebase. " HOST                                            
      ;;
   esac
 done
```

The idea is you have a loop that never stops (thanks to `true`), but your desired input results in a `break` statement that, well, breaks execution of the loop, while the catch-all case statement allows the loop to continue.

You might want to add an "exit/cancel" option of some sort if you do not want to have to CTRL-C out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Fred! I think I'll take your advice and add an exit option. Otherwise, I'd be going around in circles....*roll on snare drum*

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=$1

while [[ "$HOST" != "heroku" && "$HOST" != "firebase" ]]
do
  read -p "You can only choose between heroku and firebase. " HOST
done

case "$HOST" in
heroku)
 echo git push heroku master
 ;;
firebase)
 echo firebase deploy
 ;;
esac
```

Compared to [Fred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052528/6394138), the advantage is that checking of the argument and the main body of the script are separated, whereas the disadvantage is that if you have to add more cases, you will have to do it in two places.